# PowerShell Equivilent to Select-Object "-ExpandProperty" for Where-Object To Query Nested Objects

Tags: powershell, select, where-clause

I have the following code:

```
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "XXX" -Credential $cred 

$results.value | Where-Object releaseDefinition.name -eq "XYZ"
```

For some reason isn't not returning any results, when I run a equivilent "Select-Obejct" query on it, the issue becomes clear:

```
$results.value | Select-Object releaseDefinition.name
```

All empty.. and google says I need to use [the "-ExpandProperty" tag to do this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7)

```
$results.value | Select-Object releaseDefinition -ExpandProperty name
```

So I try to do the same for my "Where-Object" statement:

```
$results.value | Where-Object releaseDefinition -ExpandProperty name -eq "XYZ"
```

and it error's... Because [that property doesn't exist.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) So I need to find a different way to accomplish this task, how can I accomplish the code above without using this parameter? Also why does this parameter exist on the select and not on the where clause?

Comment: The [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet selects specified **properties** of an object or set of objects.  
The [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet selects **objects** that have particular property values from the collection of objects that are passed to it. I guess `releaseDefinition` is an embedded object. Please, add a (sample) of the input object (`$Result | ConvertTo-Json`) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bit of a workaround, if you wrap you statement in parenthesis and reference the base element($_) you can access element at any level of the object:

```
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "XXX" -Credential $cred 

$results.value | Where-Object { $_.releaseDefinition.name -eq "XYZ" }
```

Comment: Thanks for this example David. The example seems to currently be missing parenthesis.